# Fechar ou Sinalizar?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, fechamento, sinalização

Considerando esta questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15908/2-selects-o-primeiro-influencia-o-segundo

O problema foi que o autor da pergunta esqueceu de incluir o jQuery. O problema foi resolvido incluindo o jQuery - conforme o próprio autor relata em comentário. (Ainda bem que ele deixou o comentário!) Enfim: não tem nada a ver com o código postado e/ou o foco da pergunta feita (selects interconectados).

Eu cliquei em "fechar", selecionei um motivo, e um comentário com minha justificativa foi acrescentado.

Essa foi a ação correta? Eu deveria ter "sinalizado" ao invés de fechado? Eu poderia sinalizar **também**, além de já ter votado para fechar? Isto seria correto e/ou apropriado?

E, de maneira mais genérica: quando **fechar** e quando **sinalizar**? Qual é a diferença entre os dois? Faz sentido votar para fechar **e** sinalizar também?

Comment: Relacionada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/514/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-apenas-procuram-code-review-for-typos

Comment: Tem uma coisa que não está aqui na pergunta que é *Votar Negativamente* (a tooltip diz claramente: **"...não é útil"**). E quando a pergunta tem suficientes votos negativos (e outras condições que preciso confirmar) o delete automático pode acontecer bastante rápido (creio). cc/ @bfavaretto

Comment: Curiosamente, apesar de ser um caso para exclusão imediata, penso que não é um caso para *votar negativamente* e prejudicar a reputação do novato.

Comment: Ele tem reputação 1, não perde nada com o voto contra. Mas vou retirar para não parecer agressivo, no estilo paz e amor proposto pelo Gabe. [Edit: não dá mais, só se a pergunta foi editada].

Comment: Tem também o caso citado pelo @brasofilo de que o sistema apaga automaticamente perguntas fechadas  com placar zero ou menor e sem respostas com placar positivo, após 9 dias (ou um pouco mais tarde com condições um pouco diferentes). Ver http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006

Comment: @bfavaretto, fiz um edit lá pra desfazer meu -1 o_= . . . Achei esta outra referência também: [How does deleting work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that?lq=1)

Comment: Será que dá para fazer um compêndio dessas informações objetivas espalhadas nos comentários aqui como uma resposta a essa nova pergunta que fiz aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1354/como-uma-pergunta-que-pode-e-deve-ser-excluida-e-efetivamente-removida-do-site

Comment: E se eu fosse pesquisar no google a mesma pergunta que ele postou e achasse esse post no SO? O codigo dele que a principio não funcionava por um erro bobo está correto e me ajudaria. Vendo desse ponto de vista nesse caso eu não deletaria a questão. Apenas iria sugerir que o código fosse postado novamente como resposta e com a descrição do engano (no caso esquecer de carregar o jquery), sendo que até isso pode ser útil para alguém mega iniciante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Essa foi a ação correta? Eu deveria ter "sinalizado" ao invés de fechado? Eu poderia sinalizar também, além de já ter votado para fechar? Isto seria correto e/ou apropriado?

**Sim e não**.

A função das sinalizações é justamente delegar a um moderador algo que você não pode resolver sozinho. No caso de fechamento, o seu voto é apenas um entre os cinco necessários para que o fechamento seja efetivado. E caso você mude de ideia antes do fechamento, ainda pode removê-lo; se mudar de ideia depois do fechamento, pode votar para reabrir. Portanto, se você tem o privilégio de fechar, analisou a pergunta com atenção e considerou que deva ser fechada, não existe motivo para delegar para um moderador a decisão sobre o fechamento.

> E, de maneira mais genérica: quando fechar e quando sinalizar? Qual é a diferença entre os dois? Faz sentido votar para fechar e sinalizar também?

Acho que a diferença já ficou clara na explicação acima (me avise se não estiver).

Se faz sentido votar para fechar **e** sinalizar? Em certos casos sim, se você acha que a pergunta deve mesmo ser fechada, mas que carrega algum outro problema.

Um exemplo seria ter observado uma guerra de edições na pergunta. Não costuma ser produtivo se envolver nesse tipo de guerra, e moderadores podem acabar com elas imediatamente, bloqueando o *post*. Outro exemplo seria algum tipo de conteúdo impróprio na pergunta; mesmo que tenha sido removido em uma edição, é interessante que o moderador tenha conhecimento do ocorrido e dos responsáveis.

No caso da pergunta em questão, como apontado pelo @brasofilo, pode-se sinalizar a pergunta  se você considerar que ela merece ser excluída do site. E pessoalmente eu acho que perguntas como essa devem sim ser excluídas.

Comment: Pelo que tenho entendido no SOEN, se o post merece ser *deletado*, além de votar pra fechar também podemos sinalizá-lo como Qualidade Muito Baixa.

Comment: É verdade. E isso quer dizer que minha resposta estava errada, porque essa pergunta é um bom exemplo de conteúdo que pode ser deletado. Vou editar.

Comment: Ah, e se já tem 4 votos pra fechar, temos que sinalizar *primeiro*, pois depois de fechada já não aparece a opção QMB.

Comment: @brasofilo Para de invalidar minha resposta! :D

Comment: Parece então que a única saída após o fechamento seria sinalizar com motivo customizado, indicando ao moderador que pode ser um caso para exclusão. Porque se o flag QMB some após o fechamento, a pergunta deve sair da fila de análise QMB também.

Comment: Acho que depois de fechada não tem sentido incomodar a moderação com uma flag personalizada. Não sei dizer o que acontece, nunca tive acesso a ferramentas de moderador ou de usuário 20k.

Comment: "Você deve esperar que uma pergunta fique encerrada por 2 dias antes de poder votar pela exclusão. Esta restrição está removida para usuários confiáveis. Se você achar que uma publicação deve ser excluída apesar de ter vários votos ou de ser nova, sinalize-a para a atenção do moderador da comunidade." (extraído de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: Mas isso não bate com o que estou vendo no site: tenho o privilégio de usuário confiável, mas o sistema não me deixa votar para excluir essa pergunta (nem mesmo após meu -1, que habilitaria o link de excluir caso fosse uma resposta).

Comment: Opa! Tem muito mais coisa que eu não sabia nem imaginava. Esses detalhes relatados aqui nos comentários fazem muita diferença... inclusive, a diferença entre "fechar" e "excluir" é fundamental neste caso. A meu ver, a questão deve ser **excluída**, deletada mesmo, por ter se tornado pura e simples *perda de tempo* (em inglês, como foi [linkado](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/514/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-apenas-procuram-code-review-for-typos) pelo @bigown, temos o "unlikely to help future readers" - que eu selecionaria se encontrasse o equivalente em português)...

Comment: Quer dizer que se eu me deparo com algo que - conforme meu entendimento - deve ser **excluído**, ao invés de **fechar** seria melhor **sinalizar** solicitando a exclusão? (Exatamente o caso da pergunta em questão.)

Comment: @J.Bruni Se a pergunta precisa ser fechada, vote para fechar, independentemente da necessidade de exclusão ou não. Sinalizar seria uma atitude *adicional*.