# Como uma pergunta pode ser excluída e efetivamente removida do site?

Tags: suporte, exclusão

A minha pergunta aqui é estritamente técnica e objetiva, visando a esclarecer o mecanismo de funcionamento do *site*.

Algumas "perguntas" são bem fáceis de classificar como merecedoras de **exclusão**. Por exemplo, um *spam* explícito - como uma propaganda de *shampoo*... ou simplesmente o caso de alguém "brincando" e colocando perguntas totalmente nada a ver, como: "Para qual time de futebol vocês torcem?"

Nestes casos de "exclusão óbvia", onde todos são unânimes em entender que o conteúdo não pertence ao *site*... qual o caminho das pedras? Quem pode efetivamente remover o conteúdo? Quais as condições? É preciso um número de votos negativos? É preciso que a pergunta esteja fechada? É preciso ser super-usuário (ou moderador ou coisa do tipo)? Quais as regras de exclusão automática, caso existam?

Gostaria de saber a resposta objetiva, técnica, de como o sistema está preparado, as ferramentas que dispõe e como funcionam.

Penso também que ter o conhecimento dos mecanismos pode ajudar a nós, membros da comunidade, a tomar as ações mais acertadas... (entre votar negativo, fechar, editar, comentar, sinalizar, etc)

P.S. - Esta pergunta é sequência desta outra aqui no Meta ([Fechar ou Sinalizar?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1350/fechar-ou-sinalizar)). Nela, [o caso em questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15908/2-selects-o-primeiro-influencia-o-segundo) não é tão exagerado quanto os exemplos apontados aqui. Não se trata de *spam* nem loucura ou brincadeira. Mas é uma pergunta que uma análise rápida deixa claro que a remoção do conteúdo significa um benefício para a qualidade do site.

Comment: Dada a resposta, isto pode virar [meta-tag:proposta-para-faq]. Vai ser uma resposta longa pois a coisa é complexa. E já adianto que spam é um caso à parte, que deve ser sempre sinalizado (o sistema exclui como spam após determinado número de sinalizações, e penaliza o responsável com -100 e, se não me engano, algum tipo de suspensão).

Comment: Ok. Depois de fazer a pergunta é que vi a [pergunta equivalente no meta em inglês](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), bem como a [referência sobre exclusão automática, em inglês](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year). Acho que será ótimo termos documentado aqui no Meta em português. É trabalho para quem sabe bem como o sistema funciona (e/ou um trabalho de tradução também).

Answer (score 22):

## Publicações podem ser excluídas...

### ... por usuários:

- **Você** pode excluir suas próprias publicações imediatamente usando o botão de "deletar" logo abaixo dele. Salvo se for uma resposta que já foi marcada como *aceita* ou se é uma pergunta com mais de uma resposta ou ao menos uma resposta com voto positivo.
- **Moderadores** podem deletar qualquer coisa com efeito imediatato.
- **Usuários com o privilégio [*Ferramentas do Moderador*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)** (reputação >= 10k ou 2k em betas) podem votar para deletar perguntas que estão fechadas há mais de 48 horas. O número de votos necessários é calculado pela fórmula:

  ```
  min(10, 3 + (votos_na_pergunta + votos_na_melhor_resposta) / 20)
  ```
- **Usuários com o privilégio [*Usuário Confiável*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)** (reputação >= 20k ou 4k em betas) podem deletar sem esperar 48 horas depois de fechar se a pergunta tiver pontuação de ao menos **-3**. Adicionalmente, podem votar para deletar *respostas* com pontuação negativa. São necessários 3 votos para efetivar.
- **Usuários com o privilégio [*Editar Perguntas e Respostas*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)** (reputação >= 2k ou 1k em betas) podem ver a [fila de análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review) de publicações de baixa qualidade e lá marcar "recomendar exclusão". São necessários 6 votos.

### ... pelo sistema:

O sistema é representado pelo usuário [**Comunidade**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1) que realiza ações baseadas em alguns gatilhos. Uma **pergunta** será deletada automaticamente se:

- **Tem mais de *30 dias* e...**

  - tem pontuação negativa
  - não tem respostas
  - não esta bloqueada (*locked*)
- **...ou...**

  - ela foi fechada e migrada para um site diferente
- **Tem mais de *365 dias* e...**

  - tem uma pontuação de **0** *ou* uma pontuação de **1** e seu dono encerrou a conta no site
  - não tem respostas
  - não está bloqueada
  - tem uma contagem de visitas menor que a idade da pergunta em dias vezes `1.5`
  - tem não mais que **1** comentário
- **Foi fechada há mais de *9 dias* e...**

  - não foi fechada como duplicata
  - tem pontuação de **0** ou inferior
  - não está bloqueada
  - não tem respostas positivadas
  - não tem uma resposta aceita
  - não tem votos pendentes pela reabertura
  - não foi editada nos últimos **9** dias

Perguntas excluídas pelo sistema incluem o seguinte aviso:

<kbd>[image: examplo da notificação "excluída por Comunidade"]</kbd>

---

**Fontes em inglês:**

- [Gatilhos para o usuário **Comunidade** deletar perguntas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/177950)
- [Como a exclusão de publicações funciona?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/246288)
- [Quantidade de votos para deletar perguntas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071)