# As duplicadas devem ser negativadas?

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas, voto-contra, votos

É certo dar negativos nas duplicadas?

como por exemplo neste caso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16556/) em que o que duplicou ganhou mais pontos positivos do que o autor que fez a pergunta primeiro? futuramente possivelmente o site pode estar cheio de duplicatas que foram feitas para ganhar upvotes, que não estou dizendo que se aplica a esse caso

**nota:** eu não negativei a pergunta duplicada isso é apenas uma dúvida

Comment: Boa pergunta, também tenho achado estranho, acho que deviam estar negativadas, porque NORMALMENTE, querem dizer que houve falta de pesquisa do utilizador. Mas como ainda somos poucos e muitos de nós ainda nem viram uma pergunta assim votam +1.

Comment: @JorgeB. e pior ainda pode haver casos que possam fazer a pergunta propositalmente mesmo sabendo que é uma duplicada só para ganhar pontos.

Comment: Sim pode vir a criar esse tipo de situações, mas para já acho que tem sido só mesmo por falta de pesquisa dos utilizadores, e falta de pessoas com experiência para negativar a resposta.

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, por isso para não haver mal-entendido até coloquei na pergunta "que não estou dizendo que se aplica a esse caso"

Comment: @JorgeB. acabaram de dar mais um [upvote](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16556/qual-a-diferenca-entre-arquivos-encodados-com-bom-e-sem-bom) mesmo sabendo que é uma duplicada

Comment: Eu tenho reparado nisso, as vezes uma pergunta acaba de sair, tem um texto grande e já está a levar com +1. O povo anda "cheio de fome" de upvote :P

Comment: Para melhorar já leva umas quantas edições ;) @Erlon Charles

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha comentei a pergunta te explicando o motivo de ela não ser duplicada e de estarmos falando de coisas diferente, embora as respostas possa conter elementos relacionados

Comment: @ErlonCharles sim mas lembrando que não foi apenas eu que votei para fechar eu sou apenas 1 e são necessário 5 votos para fechar, ou seja, outras pessoas também analisaram e viram que a pergunta é uma duplicada.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha eu sei, estou falando para você, pois você levantou a questão :) e acredito que se elas lerem tanto estes comentários quanto os da questão poderam reconsiderar sua avaliação ou não.

Comment: @ErlonCharles sim, talvez realmente sua pergunta pode até não ser uma duplicada mas o motivo de eu fazer essa pergunta aqui é que realmente em outros casos pessoas que duplicaram ganham pontos que não deveriam ganhar(mas lembrando que não estou falando do seu caso)

Comment: Por isso essa é uma questão tão boa de ser discutida, irei postar meu entendimento de *downvotes* como resposta.

Comment: Isso e o que deve ser considerado duplicado ou não daria uma boa discussão.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sugiro a leitura [desse post no blog do StackExchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) (em inglês). Pelo que eu entendi (desse post e de outras leituras no MSE) nem toda duplicação é ruim, tampouco é indício  [por si só] de que o OP não fez o dever de casa. Traduzindo livremente do post acima:

> Uma coisa que quero deixar clara, entretanto, é que duplicação não é necessariamente ruim. Pelo contrário - *alguma* duplicação é desejável. Existe o benefício óbvio de ter múltiplas variantes sutis de uma pergunta, já que as pessoas tendem a perguntar e pesquisar usando palavras completamente diferentes, e quanto melhor nossa cobertura, maiores as chances que as pessoas poderão encontrar a resposta que estão procurando. (...)
>
> Indo além, é OK perguntas duplicadas terem respostas duplicadas. Embora você poderia argumentar que as perguntas duplicadas poderiam todas serem mescladas em uma única pergunta com um conjunto "mestre" de resposta, isso é meio que irritante do ponto de vista do usuário procurando por uma resposta. Ponha-se no lugar dele. Em vez de encontrar:
>
> ```
> Pergunta Duplicada
> ---
> Resposta Duplicada
> ```
>
> Ele teria que lidar com:
>
> ```
> Pergunta Duplicada
> ---
> [fechada como duplicata da Pergunta] clique aqui para ver as respostas
> ```

Na minha opinião, é bom sim fechar certas perguntas como duplicatas, pois se uma pergunta pede uma resposta mais detalhada e elaborada, é melhor só fazer isso uma vez do que várias. Mas nada impede que perguntas parecidas sejam feitas, com respostas simples seguida de "para mais detalhes, clique aqui". Por isso minha opinião é que **não**, não se deve votar negativamente em perguntas duplicadas, e nem em respostas para essas perguntas duplicadas (mas continuar fechando essas perguntas, se forem mesmo duplicatas de outra).

P.S. Do ponto de vista da gamificação, faz sentido o que você falou: vampiros/sanguessugas criando perguntas duplicadas por falta de esforço, e ***/garimpeiros respondendo-as para ganhar upvotes. Sempre achei que o SE deveria recompensar de alguma forma quem acha duplicatas, pra estimular esse comportamento. Mas na ausência disso, o jeito é continuar contando com a boa vontade de quem faz esse esforço.

---

**Atualização:** uma coisa que esqueci de considerar na resposta é o [mecanismo de auto-remoção](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1354/215). Se uma pergunta está fechada, e satisfaz certos critérios, ela é automaticamente removida do site após um período de 9 dias. Entretanto, [há uma exceção explícita pra perguntas fechadas como duplicatas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/177950) - já que não é o objetivo do sistema que esse tipo de pergunta seja excluída.

Pois bem, e o que acontece se essa pergunta *também* estiver negativada? Nesse caso ela pode se enquadrar no outro critério de remoção, que é ter pontuação de `-1` ou menos, nenhuma resposta, e não estiver "locked" (não sei bem como é isso). Ou seja, negativar pode fazer com que uma pergunta que a princípio não seria removida o seja (além é claro da chance do próprio autor remover para recuperar os pontos de reputação perdidos).

Isso reforça minha opinião que não se deve votar negativamente numa pergunta que seja boa, apesar de ser duplicada. Já que isso destrói o propósito de ter uma mesma pergunta expressa de modos diferentes (e portanto indexada pelos motores de busca de uma forma diferente). Mesmo que o OP ganhe alguma reputação por isso, e daí? Não é como se alguém pudesse ganhar pontos consistentemente fazendo só isso por muito tempo, sem que alguém perceba que tem algo de errado...

Comment: Acredito que o downvote serviria para avisar o usuário que da próxima vez ele procure bem antes de fazer uma duplicada e até causar medo, porque se eu não tenho medo de fazer duplicada eu não vou me importar em pesquisar e ver se existe e ainda mais seria certo eu ganhar pontos pela duplicada?

Comment: Dando como exemplo [**esta pergunta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16556/qual-a-diferenca-entre-arquivos-encodados-com-bom-e-sem-bom) eu fiz pesquisas no SOPT para ver se seria duplicada, mas muito provavelmente a pergunta q eu fiz se encaixa exatamente no que o @mgibsonbr postou a citação "pessoas tendem a perguntar e pesquisar usando palavras completamente diferentes", portanto esse tipo de "punição" não é tão interessante. Se você pode fazer? Com Certeza. Se isso vai ajudar a comunidade? Duvido muito.

Comment: Eu recebi alguns *downvotes* por ela e não faço a menor de porque e sinceramente pouco me importo com os *downvotes* eu quero é ter minha pergunta respondida.

Comment: Eu concordo. Julgo as perguntas por seu próprio mérito. Se é ruim, merece downvote, sendo duplicata ou não. O fato de ser duplicata só me levaria a um downvote se for algo muito óbvio – coisa que não temos aqui ainda, mas no SO em inglês é bem comum, perguntas que aparecem várias vezes ao dia, todo dia.

Comment: @ErlonCharles talvez o erro tenha sido meu por usar a sua pergunta como exemplo que não é uma perfeita duplicada, mas se fosse uma pergunta duplicada mesmo aí sim acredito que valeria os downvoters perfeitamente, porque os downvote não são para punir mas são para evitar que a pessoa saía "beneficiada" de uma pergunta que não é dela.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha Não concordo com esse uso do downvote, a menos que isso seja recorrente (i.e. o usuário está abusando/demonstrando má fé). O fato de alguém ser beneficiado esporadicamente por algo que outro já perguntou antes não deveria ser um problema. Hehe, isso me lembrou das confusões e brigaiadas envolvendo o sistema de patentes... :P

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha sem problemas cara, aconteceu exatamente a mesma coisa com essa pergunta [**aqui**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5314/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-saber-se-uma-url-esta-funcionando), que também é minha, também levei *downvotes*, também não sei o motivo e também não me importo com isso.

Comment: @ErlonCharles entendi o que aconteceu com sua pergunta, a minha pergunta tinha um conteúdo mas você queria mais detalhes e não teria como mudar a pergunta o que você pode fazer ou melhor nós podemos fazer é quando for postar uma pergunta que pode ser confundida como duplicada seria bom se a gente colocasse o link e explicando a situação por exemplo: Eu dei uma olha nessa pergunta e ela é o que eu queria porem tem alguns detalhes que não tem nela e por isso estou fazendo essa pergunta semelhante mais com detalhes mais aprofundados; acho que fazendo dessa forma podemos evitar mal-entendidos

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha na verdade eu nem consegui a localizar sua pergunta na pesquisa prévia que fiz. Hehe, mas tanto faz, basta manter a frequência respondendo, perguntando editando e analisando no SOPT que *reputation* medalhas e etc sobe, só é necessário tomar cuidado, mas deslizes acontecem e sempre vão acontecer, independente de se eu tenho 15k ou 300 de *reputation*.

Comment: Essa sua pergunta levantou uma questão bem interessante de ser discutida, tem muitos *downvotes* que eu não entendo porque foram dados, em perguntas minhas e em várias perguntas de vários outros e seria muito bom obter um esclarecimento sobre como tratar isso para poder procurar uma boa forma de instrução e de autopoliciamento.

Answer (score 7):

Não acredito que duplicatas precisem ser negativadas, o simples fato de haver a possibilidade de marcar uma pergunta como uma possível duplicata de outra já é o suficiente para indicar ao perguntador que ele procure antes de fazer perguntas similares ou idênticas à perguntas existente.

A quantidade de pontos que se perde com um *downvote* é bem menor que a quantidade de pontos q se ganha com um *upvote*(se 3 pessoas votarem a favor e 3 votarem contra o perguntador ainda terá 9 pontos positivos), então o voto puro e simples não ajuda a entender as boas práticas da comunidade.

Para mim *downvotes* servem como um alerta de que a pergunta(ou resposta) contém algo errado e que precisa ser corrigido, sendo assim, é  [**altamente recomendado**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/652/voto-negativo-sem-justificativa-e-valido?answertab=votes#tab-top) que em cada *downvote* seja também comentado o motivo de ter sido dado ou dar um *upvote* em um comentário que seja de acordo com seu voto, para que assim aquele que perguntou (ou respondeu) tenha a oportunidade de entender o que há de errado com sua postagem e fazer todas as correções pertinentes.

Procuro usar poucos *downvotes*, antes de fazer uso dessa funcionalidade eu procuro ter certeza que uma simples edição ou que perguntas simples não possam me esclarecer e me fazer não dar um *downvote*

Comment: Downvote serve para isso mesmo, discordar com a pergunta ou com a resposta. Se eu achar que não está no escopo, ou simplesmente achar uma pergunta que demonstre falta de pesquisa dou down. Imagina que agora todos nos do SOPT criávamos agora [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/7210), levávamos todos upvotes, só porque é uma boa pergunta? Ou seria dar downvotes a todos porque nem pesquisaram que já existiam varias iguais?

Comment: Concordo com a parte do downvote mas você se esqueceu de falar da questão principal da pergunta: As duplicadas devem ser negativadas?

Comment: E nesse caso o downvote serviria para avisar o usuário que da próxima vez ele procure bem antes de fazer uma duplicada e até causar medo, porque se eu não tenho medo de fazer duplicada eu não vou me importar em pesquisar e ver se existe e ainda mais seria certo eu ganhar pontos pela duplicada?

Comment: Boa observação, editei a resposta

Comment: Concordei com essa resposta e acho que é a mais simples e direta. Eu não acho que o usuário tem obrigação em procurar um assunto existente e  encontrar rspostas nos resultados da busca pois o sistema de busca do Stack é "ineficiente". Muitas vezes temos que ter o trabalho de ir até o Google para encontrar um tópico dentro do Stack. E outro motivo é que muitas perguntas e respostas possuem títulos fora do comum, o que dificulta a busca. Por isso, muitos acabam abrindo tópicos duplicados. Um negativo é justo quando a pergunta é ruim, mas quando é duplicada, basta marcar como duplicada.