# Perguntas duplicadas com votos positivos. Pode isso?

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas, votos

Porque algumas perguntas mesmo sendo duplicadas recebem votos positivos?

Vi essa pergunta hoje:

[Duvida a respeito da exclamação dupla (!!) em javascript / Jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93208/para-que-serve-a-exclama%C3%A7%C3%A3o-dupla-em-javascript-jquery)

E por coincidência tinha visto essa no Domingo:

[Qual o sentido de usar dupla negação em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29014/qual-o-sentido-de-usar-dupla-nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-javascript)

O cara que perguntou ganhou +2. Será que as pessoas que dão votos para a pergunta não deveriam primeiro pesquisar para ver se essa pergunta já não existe no site?

Esses positivos parecem não só dar mérito a quem não merece, mas também tira o mérito de quem já perguntou e de quem já respondeu a pergunta anteriormente feita;

Comment: [As duplicadas devem ser negativadas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/91), sim -1 :D lol, brincadeira. Duplicadas são algumas vezes boas porque facilitam as pesquisas por diferentes termos.

Comment: Wallace as perguntas por serem duplicatas não têm de ser negativadas. a pergunta até pode estar bem feita e pode ter um título diferente da duplicata. Já positivei muitas vezes duplicates e depois pus para fechar.

Comment: @rray, eu negativei tanto a pergunta como a resposta. Já têm respostas boas lá na outra página.

Comment: -1 pois sua pergunta é duplicada da que o rray mostrou (brincadeira, não negativei, mas como você se sentiria :P )

Comment: É justo @Math. Pois tenho uma ferramenta de pesquisa tão boa como o stackoverlow, eu nem sequer me dei ao trabalho de pesquisar (e digo não no google, mas dentro do próprio site)

Comment: Engraçado que há um ano atrás eu tinha uma opinião diferente. Eu a ver comentários meus e a pensar "quem foi o anormal que escreveu isto" ah fui eu lol.

Comment: Se não merecem negativos, pelo menos que não se votasse nelas!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters depende da pergunta, pode ou não merecer negativos.

Comment: Ativaram a funcionalidade de alterar os sinais dos +1 e -1 nos comentários xD

Comment: Com assim @rray? kkk

Comment: @WallaceMaxters como você mesmo disse, **tenho uma ferramenta de pesquisa tão boa como o stackoverlow**. Mas essa ferramenta só é possível com a base de dados. Uma pergunta duplicada pode ser expressada de formas diferentes, como no exemplo que você mostrou. O OP não sabia "O que pesquisar". Eu mesmo já achei muitas respostas do que procurava em "duplicadas". E com isso, fui até a pergunta ver a resposta. Não acho que merece ser negativada, porém, se a pergunta foi "bem expressada", pq não votar nela? Não estou falando para votar em todas, pelo contrário, analisar todas e ver se merece o voto.

Comment: Acho que entendo o que você disse @Randrade. Existem perguntas parecidas e existem perguntas idênticas. Existe algumas parecidas, que a resposta responde ela mesmo assim.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters É complicado criar "uma regra", mas analisar cada pergunta antes "não custa nada". Veja bem, uma pessoa, por mais experiente que seja, as vezes pode não saber **"O que e/ou como pesquisar"**. Com isso, marcando como duplicada terá duas ou mais chances da resposta ser encontrada. Não vejo um lado negativo com isso, pelo contrário.

Comment: Que ironia! A sua pergunta negativada sobre perguntas negativadas e duplicadas está sendo fechada como duplicata... Sua pergunta sobre duplicatas negativadas em breve poderá ser também uma duplicata negativada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, eu acho que a resposta do mgibsonbr responde perfeita e tecnicamente esta daqui e estou votando pra fechar como duplicata. Devo admitir, porém, que a ironia não perdida no caminho!

Answer (score 10):

Meus caros, acredito que cada um aqui pode julgar de forma positiva ou negativa a minha pergunta como acharem necessário, porem, quero apontar alguns detalhes aqui que gostaria que vocês levassem em consideração:

Minha [publicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93208/para-que-serve-a-exclama%C3%A7%C3%A3o-dupla-em-javascript-jquery?noredirect=1#comment188866_93208), qual chamarei de P1 (pergunta 1).

Possível [publicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29014/qual-o-sentido-de-usar-dupla-nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-javascript) cuja a qual eu estaria duplicando, qual chamarei de P2 (pergunta 2).

- O titulo da pergunta:

P1: [Duvida a respeito da exclamação dupla (!!) em javascript / Jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93208/para-que-serve-a-exclama%C3%A7%C3%A3o-dupla-em-javascript-jquery)

P2: [Qual o sentido de usar dupla negação em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29014/qual-o-sentido-de-usar-dupla-nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-javascript)

Primeiramente, não consegui localizar a pergunta a devido ao fato da pergunta estar sendo referida como "dupla negação", pois bem, como dito na primeira resposta de P2, não se trata de uma dupla negação e sim de " uma maneira rápida de converter o resultado de uma expressão para um valor booleano". Se raciocinarmos, há um pequeno equivoco já no titulo da pergunta.

- A pergunta em si:

P1:

"Para que serve a exclamação dupla (!!) e como utiliza-la?

Ela é algo nativo de Javascript ou criada entre as funcionalidades da própria Jquery?

OBS.: gostaria de um exemplo da utilização na resposta."

P2: "Qual a lógica de se fazer esse tipo de operação?"

Notem aqui que o sentido da pergunta se dá de forma diferente. EU QUERO SABER o que é a exclamação dupla, se vocês notarem é algo diferente de saber "qual é a lógica para se utilizar isso". Também pergunto como utiliza-la, talvez seja esse o conteúdo que o nosso caro @WallaceMaxTerns apontou como replicado o qual posso modificar se necessário. Porém agora mais um detalhe, que eu gostaria que vocês me ajudassem a procurar... Onde está a parte, da P2, que fala sobre ser uma função ser "nativa Javascript ou Jquery"? Se alguém encontrar por favor, me mostre!

Pois bem, não estou criticando a abertura do tópico, mas acredito que foi algo totalmente desnecessário, pois o tempo que estou levando para mostrar a diferença entre uma pergunta e outra é o mesmo tempo que eu poderia levar para achar a resposta para o meu problema, sendo que, qualquer um que lê-se as duas perguntas com atenção e tenta-se compreender o sentido de cada uma, veria que a grande diferença entre ambas.

Agora, que já demonstrei a diferença para vocês, como solução sugiro que aqueles que acham a pergunta duplicada me ajudem a apontar os pontos duplicados para que eu possa remodelar a pergunta.

---

**Para finalizar minha posição, gostaria de apenas referenciar que esse tópico me parece já respondido [nesse outro](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378/as-duplicadas-devem-ser-negativadas), discutido algum tempo atras aqui no meta.**

Comment: Essa questão do jQuery é que me fez remover o voto negativo do IvanFerrer. Não positivei, mas removo o negativo.

Comment: Isso ai tem outras linguaguens também, veja [essa pergunta de C](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4018/91) apesar de um pouco diferente a ideia é a mesma, converter algo para booleano. Essa funcionalidade fica mais evidente em linguagens onde a tipagem faz diferença.

Comment: O que a sua pergunte tem a mais, que não é respondido pela outra?

Comment: Cuide para suas alterações não invalidarem a reposta. Ainda vejo que a pergunta é mesma coisa. não entendi exatamente o que você quer saber.

Comment: Sim, foi tomado cuidado para na invalidar a resposta @rray.

Comment: @DorivalZanetto considere olhar a minha resposta (eu havia comentado aqui mas ficou muito grande): http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4459/3635

Answer (score 10):

Desculpe Wallace, entendo seu ponto de vista mas **não concordo** inteiramente (isto quer dizer que concordo em parte, mas não em tudo).

### Veja as situações:

- Algumas vezes a pergunta criada depois esta muito melhor escrita que primeira
- Perguntas duplicatas e com bons títulos ajudam a chegar nas perguntas com respostas
- As vezes o título da pergunta ou até o texto do corpo não facilitam pesquisar

Eu mesmo criei a uma semana atrás uma pergunta que já tinha resposta, mas o título e o corpo da pergunta pouco tinham haver com o problema, a resposta era bem especifica mas a pergunta não, então o @Sergio me comunicou que era uma duplicata, eu mesmo marquei a minha como duplicata, nisso eu já havia:

- +2 e um -1 na pergunta (provavelmente um -1 por ser uma duplicata)
- +3 na resposta

Veja o meu ponto de vista, eu ganhei votos e já existia uma resposta, mas a minha pergunta foi bem especifica e não falava de `.html()` de `alert` ou qualquer outra coisa (que foi o que dificultou encontrar), a minha pergunta é ao meu ver muito boa como referencia pra resposta já existente e acho que então mereci o +2 pois criei um boa referencia sim.

**Claro** que isto não significa que devemos duplicar tudo que tem títulos ruins ou poucos específicos, mas ainda sim podem nascer duplicatas e elas servirão de referência.

Obviamente que não vou negar que existe preguiça pela parte de alguns, mas no caso aqui que estamos discutindo o título da pergunta mais antiga usa o termo *dupla negação*, realmente duvido que o autor da duplicata (@DorivalZanetto) sabia que o nome era este e note também que nem o StackOverflow e nem o Google interpretam bem alguns sinais, as vezes podemos usar aspas `"!"` pra ajudar o buscador, mas não é com tudo que irá funcionar.

**Então** no caso **aqui** discutido, acho que @DorivalZanetto forneceu uma boa duplicata como referencia de pesquisa.

### Conclusão

Existem dois tipos de duplicata:

- Duplicata ruim, que é por fata de pesquisa sim
- Duplicata boa, que geralmente é mais intuitiva pra quem futuramente tiver a mesma duvida
- Não é porque a duplicata é boa que devemos realmente duplicar
- Se criou uma boa referencia de pesquisa pra outra pergunta que já tem resposta, então acho que merece sim alguns pontos

Alguns detalhes do mecanismo do sistema aqui [nesta resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1380/3635)

---

### Resposta ao @DorivalZanetto

- Sobre quem negativou

  O problema é que não existe um sistema de notificação pras perguntas que negativamos, ou seja não tem como quem votou negativo saber que você editou tão facilmente e assim retirar os votos.
- Sobre a sua pergunta e **porque acho que ela é uma duplicata**

  Pra entender o porque a pergunta é duplicata, tenho que explicar um pouco da *dupla negativa*. A questão é porque a *dupla negativa* não é um *operador*, mas sim dois *operadores lógicos*, ele (`!`) é comum em várias linguagens e o uso duplo dele tem o efeito **parecido** com `!(!)` ou `!false` ou `!null`, ou seja você pode fazer isto infinitamente, por exemplo: `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!true`.

  Então `!` é negativa de `!` que é negativa de `!` que é negativa de `!` que é negativa de `!` que é negativa de `!` que é negativa de `!` que é negativa de `!` que é negativa de `!` que é negativa de `!` que é negativa de `!` que é ... que é negativa de `true`.

  Em minha opinião digo que não importa, o `!!` não é um operador especifico, especifico é o `!` sozinho. O que importa **realmente** é entender como isto funciona e a outra pergunta já responde isto.

  *Dupla negativa* não é uma coisa "especifica" é mais uma "hack" e se você entender os operadores e as *ifs* vai entender que isto não é igual a fazer `&&` que podemos dizer que é especifico.

  É como eu disse é apenas a *negação da negação*, igual quando você faz isto `!variable` só que ao invés de uma negação de `variavel`, você estará "negando a negação" ao usar `!!...`, ou seja e reforçando, o uso de `!!` não é especifico.

  Com isto entendido, então fica claro que a outra resposta já responde como funciona a dupla negação e que se uma linguagem usa `!` como negação, então provavelmente ela vai suportar dupla negação.

  Só digo uma coisa, se a resposta de uma pergunta existente não lhe satisfaz, você pode comentar na resposta pedindo mais detalhes ou lançar uma recompensa por novas respostas :)