# O que é melhor, deixar fechar a pergunta ou remover?

Tags: suporte

Quando uma pergunta minha é considerada duplicata, ou não pertencente ao escopo do SOpt, ou em casos afins e então ela recebe votos para ser fechada.

Eu concordando que o voto recebido para ser fechada realmente tem sentido, o que é recomendado fazer, ou qual a melhor opção: deixar ser fechada, inclusive votar a favor para ela ser fechada ou remover diretamente? No caso de remover estou ciente de que seria quando não possui respostas ou gratificações.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No caso de duplicatas, não é necessário remover: mesmo fechada, ela estará lá para "ajudar o Google" a encontrar respostas para a mesma pergunta expressa com palavras diferentes.

Nos demais casos, pode remover. Se ela ficar fechada por muito tempo, ela será [automaticamente removida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1558/215) mesmo, então não faz sentido esperar. A exceção é se você e/ou os demais não tiverem certeza sobre a aplicabilidade ou não da pergunta ao site - mesmo uma pergunta fechada não é excluída pelo sistema se ela tiver votação positiva, pois é sinal de que ela é uma candidata em potencial para reabertura.