# Pergunta fechada e removida (RemovedAbandonedClosed, por comunidade)

Tags: debate

Nessa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149921/comando-cmd-php

Para mim é dentro do escopo e clara o suficiente para prover uma resposta.

O AP quer simplesmente saber como enviar um comando para outro terminal (outro Pc na rede interna) usando o PHP.

Não entendi porque foi fechada, removida, negativada e com status de `RemovedAbandonedClosed`.

Houve um equívoco muito grande nesse caso.

Estou a exagerar ou houve uma falha em fechar e excluir as postagens?

Não consigo enxergar onde tem problema para chegar a esse ponto de remover tudo.

Então qual o motivo em excluir tudo, inclusive as respostas?

Os screenshots para os que não tem acesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dos que votaram para fechar, apenas 2 tem pontuação suficiente para enxergar.

O que eu enxerguei na pergunta foi a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por isso não entendo como alguns acham que não é possível realizar a tarefa que pede a questão. É simplesmente o servidor enviar um comando para alguma estação cliente na rede *(intranet). O tal do site "aparentemente" está nesse servidor que "aparentemente" está na mesma rede. O que não está claro e concordo plenamente é sobre como está a estrutura, no entanto, eu achei isso irrelevante já o AP mencionou no que se trata de uma intranet. No último comentário do AP ficou mais claro a situação. Mas parece que ali ele ficou nervoso por ninguém estar entendendo e deve ter largado. E provavelmente não voltou mais porque votaram para fechar e o sistema foi jogando para o limbo.

Apesar de tudo, por favor, o intuito aqui não é degladiarmos para ver quem tem razão, se deve ou não fechar. Acho que é mais válido a discussão pois nesse caso há uma divergência de opiniões.

É recorrente ocorrer tais divergências e frequentemente vemos usuários, principalmente novatos e as vezes até usuários mais experientes, que ficam surpresos quando algo é fechado ou removido. Isso ocorre pois há uma falta de sintonia sobre como interpretar as normas do site. Fica algo quase que a critério da "sorte do momento" e até da boa vontade de quem tem mais recursos para poder resolver um impasse.

Comment: Pelo titulo a pergunta deve ter sido removida pelos critérios de remoção dos site. Não consigo ver porque não tenho reputação que chegue...

Comment: Sobre o "pedi para restaurar e nada foi feito": você **votou** para restaurar,  e precisa aguardar outros usuários com reputação suficiente avaliarem e votarem também se concordarem. Não existe prazo para isso, é uma coisa viva.

Comment: É que isso é um caso a parte, diferente de uma pergunta que está somente fechada e não removida. Aí a visibilidade e até interesse é muito menor ou quase nulo.  Não quero dizer que deve atender as minhas requisições em priori a de outrem.  O ponto principal que eu tinha dúvida é sobre o status de "removido" pois nunca vi isso em outras perguntas fechadas há muito mais tempo que essa em questão. Eu mesmo só percebi por acaso procurando outra coisa nada a ver.

Comment: @DanielOmine mas olha que são removidas questões frequentemente no site, quando passam por algum dos critérios de remoção.

Comment: Obrigado JorgeB, desconhecia esse recurso. Acho que é algo que poderia ser revisto e debatido pois parece que remove conteúdo útil. Dessa vez eu vi por acaso, mas imagino que deve estar jogando fora muita coisa útil.

Comment: Eu fechei porque a pergunta ficou várias em uma, tem coisas novas. O site não funciona assi, Ou pergunta tudo o que precisa ou abre uma nova pergunta, não pode ir misturando coisas novas conforme vai lembrando. Além disso a edição deixou claro que a resposta não foi lida com atenção. Desde o princípio a premissa da pergunta aqui é errada. Fora de escopo nunca foi discutido aqui.

Comment: Reabri e fechei como não clara, já que está reclamando de fora de escopo, inclusive comparando com outra que está no escopo, quando o fechamento é de não clara. A pergunta não fazia sentido antes, e faz menos ainda agora.

Comment: Reabri, mas não muda muita coisa. Acho que todos os moderadores ativos já viram isso, os usuário ativos com reputação suficiente já viram e ninguém achou que havia problema.

Comment: Quer dizer então que todos concordam que a pergunta do link não é clara o suficiente? Já provei que é simples e clara. É isso que não entendo e questiono aqui. Esse é o foco da questão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem, sou um dos que votou para fechar.

Não lembro ao certo os pormenores porque já faz uns meses, mas na minha opinião a pergunta está mal-elaborada e demonstra que quem a fez nem sabe o que é que está tentando fazer.

Quanto ao "RemovedAbandonedClosed", isso daí é resultado de um procedimento automático que apaga perguntas fechadas com votos negativos, sem respostas com votos positivos e sem atividade há algum tempo, pois esse tipo de pergunta quase sempre é apenas lixo poluindo a comunidade.

Entretanto, você me fez mudar de ideia e votei para restaurar. Quando/se ela for restaurada, dá para editar a pergunta tornando-a mais bem elaborada e reabrir.

---

Outra opção que deixo para o Daniel Omine é a de postar uma nova pergunta similar a anterior, mas dessa vez de uma forma bem elaborada. E então, postar uma resposta à sua própria pergunta. Isso tem a vantagem de ser mais simples e mais rápido, de não precisar mobilizar a comunidade e/ou os moderadores para trazer de volta dos mortos uma pergunta já há muito tempo abandonada na qual o autor provavelmente não está mais participando do site e de não trazer junto com a pergunta, os votos negativos recebidos. Caso o Marcelo de Andrade queira (autor da outra resposta), alguém pode convidá-lo a copiar a resposta antiga dele para a nova pergunta.

Comment: E eu ainda acho que as respostas dadas estão erradas, por não terem entendido o que foi perguntado. No meu entendimento o que foi pedido é outra coisa, bem diferente (e a execução está sendo feita no local errado). Justamente por isso acho que não dá pra responder sem o feedback e esclarecimento do autor. Neste ponto, uma nova pergunta refeita e clara, com uma resposta para o que foi pedido com clareza é o melhor caminho.

Answer (score 5):

> Estou a exagerar ou houve uma falha em fechar e excluir as postagens?

Minha opinião é que sim, concordo com as 5 pessoas que fecharam por não estar clara. **Não fecharam por estar fora de escopo**. Também negativaram a pergunta por baixa qualidade (pelo menos assim se espera que tenha sido o critério). Não negativei, mas ela não está muito boa mesmo.

Se discordarem a comunidade poderá reverter. Se me convenceram com argumentos claros, eu mesmo reverto.

> Então qual o motivo em excluir tudo, inclusive as respostas?

Porque respostas não podem existir onde não tenha pergunta. Então se a pergunta é ruim e as respostas não ajudaram nada, o sistema tem um [critério para remover o que não é útil](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1558/) (não definitivamente para que possa ser revertido, imagine que essa discussão não estaria acontecido se tivesse sido removida por completo).

Comment: Eu discordo totalmente. Pois para mim está muito simples e fácil a pergunta. Tanto é que respondi. Talvez por que confundiram a questão e não prestaram atenção ao endereço IP que é uma faixa de IP local e na edição ficou claro que é intranet. Por isso julguei que trata-se de uma intranet. Talvez por falta de conhecimento de quem votou para fechar. Pode ver como é simples resolver enviando um comando pelo exec() do PHP.. Não vejo onde não pode ser útil. Acredito que os votos de fechamento foi devido a pegunta original que não estava clara: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/149921/revisions

Comment: De fato melhorou bastante depois da edição, mas falta informação ali para dar uma resposta boa. Na resposta deixei a possibilidade de reverter. Vamos ver o que outras pessoas acham.

Comment: Para referência, aqui estão os [critérios de exclusão automática](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1558/) do site.