# Questão sem resposta e sem comentário é melhor excluir ou deixa-lá no ar?

Tags: debate, recompensa, exclusão

Abri um nova questão - [É possível ocultar o redirecionamento, mas manter a ligação para o download?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176215/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-ocultar-o-redirecionamento-mas-manter-a-liga%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-o-download), ja se passaram *48 hs* e nada de "comentário" e/ou "resposta".

Isso me ocorreu pela primeira vez, achei interessante e pensei o que fazer com *perguntas* assim. Na medida que vão sendo feitas novas perguntas na rede, naturalmente as outras vão dando seu lugar as novas, ficando perdida com o passar do tempo, em meio a tantas, deixa seu ciclo de visualização.

Comment: Deixa no ar, a pergunta é meio que especifica, mas parece boa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pode deixar, ainda pode aparecer alguém para responder, mesmo que demore. Se a pergunta for ruim, o que não parece ser o caso, ele provavelmente será fechada e negativada e aí a pergunta acabará sendo removida pelo sistema. Se ela for boa não vejo motivos para remover só porque não tem uma resposta.

Claro que se você encontrar algum motivo pessoal você até poderia remover, mas não aconselho. Se não tem mais interesse na resposta, outras pessoas podem ter.

Se você já resolveu, pode por uma resposta e até aceitá-la como correta.

Se precisa da resposta pode colocar uma recompensa para atrair mais atenção.

Se o assunto é interessante ela será localizada por alguém pesquisando na internet. Quem sabe essa pessoa coloque uma recompensa. Ou consiga uma solução e responda. Entenda que aqui fazemos perguntas para ajudar a todos e não só a nós mesmos. Me parece que esta pergunta pode ajudar outras pessoas, nem que seja só pensar no assunto.

Torço para ter uma boa resposta lá.

Comment: Bom, terei de responder por conta própria, penso comigo que a partir da resposta de minha autoria, apareça mais alguém mostrando mais alguma(s) alternativa(s) similar(es), pois ficará ainda mais claro.

Answer (score 2):

O proprio sistema remove as perguntas que não tem total de votos maior que 0 e que não tem respostas também com o total de votos maior que zero ou uma resposta aceita, isso se chama `RemovedAbandonedClosed` e ocorre automaticamente após um certo período, 30 dias ou tem mais de 365 dias ou foi fechada há mais de 9 dias, depende da situação, aqui tem detalhes de como isto funciona: [Como uma pergunta pode ser excluída e efetivamente removida do site?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1558/3635)

Por exemplo:

- Pergunta com 2 downvotes e 3 upvotes fica aberta
- Pergunta com 4 downvotes e 3 upvotes e sem respostas será removida automaticamente depois de um periodo
- Pergunta com total 0 votos e respostas também com total de 0 votos será removida automaticamente depois de um periodo
- Pergunta com 0 votos e uma resposta com um upvote, mesmo que não aceita será mantida
- Pergunta com mais downvotes, por exemplo -5 e uma resposta com total de 0 votos mas aceita será mantida.

Isso porque se tiver votos a mais que downvotes, o sistema entender que a postagem já foi útil para alguém e não vai remover (claro que tem mais critério, de uma olhada no link).

Então não precisa se preocupar em remover, o sistema fará isso, se receber upvotes é porque provavelmente é interessante ou ajudou alguém (acaso tenha respostas), então não tem porque deletar.

Comment: Agradeço por sua colaboração o texto está bem dissertativo (Dissertar é o mesmo que desenvolver ou explicar um assunto)