# Oferecer recompensa ou excluir a pergunta não respondida e fazer uma nova igual?

Tags: debate, recompensa

Obviamente que oferecer uma recompensa na pergunta a torna mais visível, pois a mesma recebe mais destaque e se cria um maior interesse dos usuários em respondê-la, mas e para usuários com menos pontos e/ou que não querem perder os pontos por mero orgulho/TOC (competitividade) ou evitar de perder certos privilégios, seria válido tal tipo de coisa? (apagar a questão e repostá-la algum tempo depois)

É fato que oferecendo uma recompensa **a pergunta será exibida na aba destaques da página inicial por sete dias**, mas e se mesmo assim não for respondida e for novamente "esquecida"?

É lógico que se a mesma não foi respondida, pode ser que ela não seja assim tão simples de se responder. Com isso alguns podem até pensar que mesmo refazendo-a (igual) a chance de ser respondida não é maior que oferecendo uma recompensa na mesma.

**"Se ela já foi feita uma vez e não obteve nenhuma resposta, fazê-la de novo para quê? Para mais uma vez não receber uma resposta?"**

Mas e se esse "processo" fosse feito mais de uma vez, de forma a constantemente a fatídica pergunta estar no meio das novas perguntas? Uma hora muito provavelmente ela receberia uma resposta e quem fez a pergunta conseguiria o que queria (**no caso a resposta**) e para isso não precisaria abrir mão de nenhum dos seus PRECIOSOS PONTOS.

Comment: E estaria burlando o sistema, portando passível de punição.

Comment: Excluir a pergunta e refaze-la não vai trazer uma resposta, só vai bagunçar mais a pagina de perguntas recentes, pode tirar o foco de outras perguntas. A recompensa não serve só para consegui uma resposta, tem outras finalidades, você pode recompensar uma resposta boa, ou buscar uma resposta canônica, depende do uso. Mas se a pergunta não recebe resposta, ou ela esta mal elaborada ou é muito especifica em algo a ponta de poucas pessoas saberem a solução.

Comment: Lembrando que nem sempre oferecer uma recompensa pode atrair atenção para uma pergunta

Comment: E como @bigown disse acima: *Vai estar burlando o sistema* e isso é errado. Tente ser o mais claro possível na hora de fazer a pergunta.

Comment: Para quê fazer de novo se pode editar?

Comment: @JorgeB.para ela voltar às primeiras páginas de perguntas

Comment: @MarceloBoni pq nn atrairia?

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso as vezes uma pergunta mesmo sendo boa, pode não haver quem saiba dar respostas, veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/182221/revisions

Comment: @MarceloBoni SIM, isso eu compreendo, mas pensando mais sobre isso, acha mais fácil alguém capaz de respondê-la, encontrá-la na página de perguntas recentes (tendo ela sido "refeita" várias vezes) ou sendo colocada uma recompensa por ela? Acho que se ela fosse "refeita" várias vezes, a longo prazo seria muito mais vista, creio que com isso a chance dela receber uma resposta seja maior.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso existem as abas [destaque](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) onde tem muito mais chance de ter alguém que se dedique a responder sua duvida (pense assim, os pontos que você perdeu ao oferecer recompensa, vão servir de incentivo para quem quiser ganhar), do que se estiver na primeira pagina da aba principal, lembrando ainda que existem a aba de [perguntas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions) que mostra somente as ultimas perguntas feitas, e a aba [principal](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/) que mostra todas perguntas recentemente **editadas**

Comment: Os dois recursos que acho que são validos nesse caso, oferecer recompensa, ou editar a pergunta puxando ela novamente pro topo da aba principal, remover e reinserir a pergunta seria uma tentativa de burlar o sistema

Comment: Eu diria que estas 3 juntas respondem https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3966/3635, https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4449/3635 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5671/3635 ou pelo menos ajudam a entender melhor o sistema do site.

Comment: @MarceloBoni de fato a chance de alguém mais capacitado (no caso da pergunta ser complexa) achar a pergunta na aba de destaques é maiorl, pois muitas pessoas (eu sou uma delas) passa a aba de perguntas recentes rapidamente atento somente às perguntas da sua área (TAG).

Answer (score 4):

Eu sugiro pensar nos seguintes pontos:

- editar a pergunta se for possível melhorá-la. Por vezes tentamos coisas que não funcionaram mas são interessantes de acrescentar à pergunta
- dá uma recompensa (se faltam pontos participa mais na comunidade para ganhar pontos)
- discute a pergunta no chat (uma ou duas vezes, nada de spam) e vê se encontras alguém que possa ajudar.

Comment: sim sim, sempre bom editar e dar uma revisada, postar o que tentou e que não deu certo.

Comment: o chat ao qual vc se refere, é aquele de toda a comunidade? (principal)

Comment: [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso sim, exato. Há uns tempos tentamos criar algumas salas de chat mais específicas, destinadas a linguagens de programação específicas mas não pegou, talvez daqui a uns tempos.