# Pergunta excluída pelo sistema não atende aos critérios

Tags: suporte, perguntas, pergunta-específica

Recentemente tive uma resposta excluída pelo sistema, aparentemente seguindo o [critério de deleção para a pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1558/28595).

Porém, como pode ser visto no link acima e na própria pergunta deletada, ela foi apagada sem atender a todos os critérios para que fosse automaticamente apagada e mesmo assim foi.

A pergunta é: [Inserir dados de um ComboBox no Banco de Dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216418/inserir-dados-de-um-combobox-no-banco-de-dados/216534#216534)

Gostaria de saber porque o sistema deletou se não havia batido com todos os critérios necessários, pois apesar da pergunta estar fechada, havia uma resposta positivada.

Já acho bastante injusto estes critérios aí, o sistema leva o post inteiro, jogando por ar o tempo despendido que tivemos respondendo e pesquisando, em muitos casos. Mas aparentemente, houve um erro neste caso ou mudaram os critérios para pior.

Answer (score 6):

A resposta linkada se baseia em outra de 2011 que é defasada. Entretanto, existe um link para atual que faz parte do FAQ.

Parece que essa pergunta foi removida pelo critério 11:

> The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a negative score when its owner’s account is deleted.

Tradução:

> O sistema deletará automaticamente quaisquer questões (e suas respectivas respostas) ou respostas com pontuação negativa quando a conta do usuário é deletada.

**Relacionada:**

[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/238766)