# Como remover o aviso "Você atingiu o limite de questões"?

Tags: suporte

Estou recebendo o seguinte aviso:

[image: Você atingiou o limite de questões]

A imagem acima já está há muito em meu perfil e não sei como voltar a fazer perguntas no Stack Overflow em Português. Eu era um simples iniciante e com diversos problemas para fazer a pergunta da forma correta.

Estou ajudando algumas pessoas para recuperar minha pontuação, mas mesmo assim ainda não voltou.

Alguém sabe o que fazer a respeito disso?

Comment: [Por que não posso mais fazer perguntas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) =>  "O veto será revogado automaticamente pelo sistema quando ele constatar que suas contribuições positivas ultrapassam as perguntas que foram mal recebidas."

Comment: Você pode melhorar suas perguntas atuais editando elas e sendo mais especifico em relação as suas dúvidas. Você pode tentar contribuir de outra forma também, respondendo, editando perguntas e respostas e votando em outros posts. Provavelmente, essas atividades positivas vão contar para remover essa restrição em sua conta.

Comment: Eu desde já dou os parabéns por demonstrar preocupacao. Quer dizer que voce está interessado em resolver o problema. Espero que tenha boas contribuicoes para resolver o seu problema :).

Comment: Você pode ler este [post do Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) para aprender como escrever uma pergunta perfeita. Acredito que vai servi de grande ajuda para você.

Comment: @gato Obrigado! Isso também é de grande ajuda!

Comment: Você tem 5 de 11 perguntas deletadas via sistema (automaticamente). Mais detalhes sobre o critério em: [Pergunta excluída pelo sistema não atende aos critérios](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6420/91)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O link [**central de ajuda**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) provavelmente afirma o motivo, mas vou resumir:

- Você deletou muitas respostas
- Você deletou muitas perguntas
- Respostas de baixa qualidade

> Provavelmente o conjunto dos 3 que lhe afetou

Você foi **vetado**, mais detalhes na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

Isto que ocorreu contigo é um **"veto"** (ou bloqueio automático de uma ação especifica), o veto não lhe impede de atuar em geral, apenas em uma atividade especifica, no seu caso creio que você esteja impedido de "perguntar" e talvez de "responder", veja como sair do veto:

> O único jeito de encerrar um bloqueio de publicação é contribuir positivamente com o site; os vetos automáticos nunca expiram nem "excedem o tempo limite". Comece corrigindo suas publicações existentes; não publique simplesmente a mesma pergunta novamente. Todas as perguntas devem ser úteis também para futuros visitantes, portanto escreva com gramática e ortografia corretas, formatando sua publicação de modo que possa ser lida facilmente e fornecendo todos os detalhes possíveis sobre seu problema e o que você já tentou. A leitura da sua pergunta em voz alta para si mesmo pode ajudar a entender como ela soa para os outros.

Ou seja, uma maneira de melhorar isto é responder perguntas de outros usuários ou restaurar uma pergunta/resposta tua deletada e tentar melhora-la, **depende muito** do que você fez **especificamente** anteriormente.

Eu não posso visualizar suas postagens deletadas, mas tenho certeza que alguma você deve conseguir editar para torna-la proveitosa novamente.

Como bem lembrado pelo @bfavareto e pelo @rray você pode clicar neste link e buscar as suas postagens deletadas (o link abaixo serve para qualquer usuário, talvez não sirva pra moderadores, mas esses caras já conhecem bem a ferramenta):

- [**is:question deleted:1**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20deleted%3A1)

> **Nota:** É claro que o veto não será removido instantaneamente, algumas coisas levam tempo, pois o sistema tem que verificar e isso não deve ser algo constante (por questão de performance do servidor provavelmente)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Até onde eu sei, eu não deletei nenhuma pergunta. Pelo que está em minha visão, apenas fiz perguntas de má qualidade, onde o público não entendeu e me classificou mau.

Como posso contribuir positivamente com a plataforma StackOverflow? Respondendo as Perguntas?

Comment: O sistema classifica as **respostas** como baixa qualidade com base na quantidade de negativos ou no numero de sinalizações ou ambos?

Comment: @gato creio que sinalização só seria valido para classificação se for deletada posteriormente (não posso afirmar), mas o downvotes estou bem certo que contam sim na avaliação do usuário.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento... Eu não tenho nenhuma pergunta deletada.

Comment: 1. Não deletei respostas...
2. Também não estou impedido de fazer novas respostas...

Comment: @ThiagoCunha Só mais um detalhe, o veto não será removido instantaneamente, algumas coisas levam tempo, pois o sistema tem que verificar e isso não deve ser algo constante (por questão de performance do servidor provavelmente). Boa sorte.

Comment: @ThiagoCunha Você tem [5 perguntas deletadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+user%3A67808+deleted%3A1).