# Botão de "publicar pergunta" travado?

Tags: debate, bug

Já aconteceu do botão "faça sua pergunta" travar? ou não funcionar? como se o usuário estivesse impedido de fazer novas perguntas, porém nenhum aviso é mostrado?

Imaginem que um usuário novo na plataforma fez uma pergunta da qual foi [fechada] ou ficou como [pendendte] por algum motivo.

Então esse mesmo usuário tenta fazer outra pergunta porém ao clicar no botão de publicar nada acontece.

O detalhe é que o campo de formulário não está bloqueado e ao clicar em "publicar a pergunta" nada acontece, nenhuma sinalização é feita.

O que fazer nessa situação? isso seria algum tipo de bug?

No contexto da minha pergunta nenhuma mensagem aparece, nada é sinalizado, diferente dessa outra [questão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6474/69614) em que o colega mostrou alguma sinalização.

Esse cenário hipotético não aconteceu comigo especificamente no SOpt, mas pode acontecer, por isso gostaria de expor o fato, caso algum iniciante se depare com esse problema.

Comment: Coloca uma imagem aí

Comment: **Talvez** você esteja bloqueado até melhorar suas contribuções na comunidade.

Comment: Descobri que era necessário passar 24h antes de liberar o acesso as novas perguntas, não sei porque, mas acabei de tentar novamente no mesmo horário de ontem.

Comment: @JonathasB.C. [Existe um limite diário de perguntas.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127567/why-are-we-limited-to-six-questions-per-day)

Comment: Não percebi ainda os -1 dados nesta pergunta, é bem interessante a pergunta. Não é um debate e sim um esclarecimento.

Comment: Eu também fiquei sem entender a motivação do -1, inclusive a resposta do Renan pareceu ser bem útil a comunidade, logo a pergunta também foi. Não lembro de ter visto pergunta igual sobre o assunto. Vou deixar um +1 (só pra constar, não é duplicata e portanto o voto de dup foi removido)

Comment: Aconteceu onde? No SOen? Se sim, é provável que tenha sido por causa [disto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360075/1328704), entretanto reparado.

Comment: @JNat foi exatamente isso, só não foi na comunidade do SOen,  valeu =]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como remover o aviso "Você atingiu o limite de questões"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6474/como-remover-o-aviso-voc%c3%aa-atingiu-o-limite-de-quest%c3%b5es)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um dos objetivos do SO é ter perguntas e respostas de alta qualidade.

Escrever uma pergunta nos padrões do SO requer esforço. Escrever uma boa pergunta requer muito esforço e dedicação. Se você faz muitas perguntas por dia, isso pode ser um sinal de que você não coloca empenho suficiente nelas.

Por esse motivo, em 2010 foi imposto em toda a rede um limite de seis perguntas por dia, e cinquenta perguntas por mês para cada usuário. O mesmo limite vale para cada endereço IP distinto. Não sei se houve alteração nesse limite de lá para cá, nem se existe nível de reputação que permita fazer mais perguntas.

De acordo com o Jeff, [perguntas boas são pérolas, enquanto perguntas medíocres são areia](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/). No mesmo espírito do limite diário de perguntas existem outras medidas para inibir perguntas ruins:

- Remoção automática de perguntas ruins;
- Bloqueio de usuários que fazem muitas perguntas negativadas;
- Delegação do poder do martelo para usuários experientes;
- Negativação de perguntas sem custo de reputação;
- Filas de revisão.

O ideal ao se fazer uma pergunta é ter certeza de que ela agregará valor não apenas para o autor, mas para toda a comunidade. Assim as poucas perguntas que nós podemos fazer terão um aproveitamento melhor.