# Perguntas não bem aceitas servem de exemplo?

Tags: debate, perguntas, voto-contra

O ideal para as perguntas que forem negativadas é deixá-las em aberto para que outros usuários vejam e não comentam o mesmo erro? Ou devem ser deletadas?

Comment: O ideal é matar elas mesmo (ou não, vide resposta). Ou deixar o sistema matar. Temos um post no meta falando sobre como não fazer perguntas, e sempre podemos atualizá-la

Comment: O sistema pode remover a pergunta de forma automática? em quais casos isso acorre? eu não sabia disso.

Comment: pergunta fechada, negativada e sem resposta um tanto velha e com poucas visitas. Tem um caso especial, talvez tenha uma explicação disso aqui no meta

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1354/64969

Comment: Fechar é diferente de deletar, logo Downvote também não tem relação direta com fechamentos ou com deletar, downvote é usado para indicar problemas, sendo da qualidade da postagem ou sendo do escopo, você usa o downvote assim como upvote como bem entender, lógico que procuramos incentivar votar pela qualidade, sobre ser deletada depende muito da pergunta, não dá para afirmar, cada caso é um caso. Claro que é opinião pessoal.

Answer (score 7):

*Fechar* é diferente de *Deletar*, uma pergunta fechada nem sempre precisa ser deletada, logo *Downvotes* também não tem relação com fechamentos ou com deletar.

Sobre servir de exemplo, eu pessoalmente discordo, tirando as *duplicatas* que são *úteis* e apontam para outras postagens, no geral as perguntas fechadas ou negativadas podem ser melhoradas e reabertas (claro que depende muito de caso a caso), leia mais sobre isso em: [Votos para fechar perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2673/3635), pois o fechamento (exceto duplicata e fora do escopo dão uma boa ideia de onde pode melhorar) e downvotes (se for mais de um provavelmente) indicam que postagem tem problemas, então fica a critério do autor, se remove e cria uma nova ou se edita e tenta melhorar.

Agora voltando **Downvotes**, eles são usados para indicar **problemas**, sendo da qualidade da postagem ou até mesmo dar enfase que uma pergunta precisa ser fechada, no entanto você usa o downvote assim como upvote como bem entender, lógico que procuramos incentivar votar pela qualidade da postagem.

Sobre ser deletada depende muito da pergunta, não dá para afirmar, cada caso é um caso, nem toda pergunta Fechada ou Negativada precisa ser deletada, se for o caso de fechamento geralmente o ideal que deve ser deletado (no meu entendimento) seriam perguntas fechadas como:

- Fora do Escopo > Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda.

Claro que não é uma obrigatoriedade, tanto que fora o deletar existe a opção de bloquear de perguntas (creio que somente moderadores podem fazer isto), por exemplo esta pergunta: [Qual a diferença entre trainee, júnior, pleno, sênior?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8116/3635)

[image: bloqueada]

### Remoção automática

Um detalhe importante é que o sistema remove perguntas sem atividades baseado em 4 critérios diferentes (pelo menos), como foi explicado em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1558/3635, detalhes:

O sistema é representado pelo usuário Comunidade que realiza ações baseadas em alguns gatilhos, uma pergunta será deletada automaticamente se:

- **Caso 1**

  - Tem mais de 30 dias
  - tem pontuação negativa
  - não tem respostas
  - não esteja **bloqueada**
- **Caso 2**

  - ela foi fechada e migrada para um site diferente
- **Caso 3**

  - Tem mais de 365 dias e...
  - tem uma pontuação de 0 ou uma pontuação de 1 e seu dono encerrou a conta no site
  - não tem respostas
  - não está bloqueada
  - tem uma contagem de visitas menor que a idade da pergunta em dias vezes 1.5
  - tem não mais que 1 comentário
- **Caso 4**

  - Foi fechada há mais de 9 dias
  - não foi fechada como duplicata
  - tem pontuação de 0 ou inferior
  - não está bloqueada
  - não tem respostas positivadas
  - não tem uma resposta aceita
  - não tem votos pendentes pela reabertura
  - não foi editada nos últimos 9 dias

---

> **Nota:** Perguntas excluídas pelo sistema incluem o seguinte aviso:
>
> [image: exemplo da notificação "excluída por Comunidade"]